# Thread safe access and modification of the custom data structure

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

Following is my custom data structures in a middle layer, which is accessed by the Multi-Threaded UI:

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<Data_Entity_Type_1>> dataList_1;

public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<Data_Entity_Type_2>> dataList_2;
```

Here, the integer key is for unique user id of a logged in user, thus each connected user will have it's on own List to work with, thus separating from other users. However, Multi- threaded access to a user's list will be via:

- UI AJAX calls to load multiple components at the same time, which can include both read and write operations.
- A single user connected via multiple devices, which can include both read and write operations.

The ConcurrentDictionary used is thread safe in all it's modification for different userid keys, but the List inside is not thread safe, it can also be accessed by multiple threads for read / write operations.

Please help me with following questions:

- Is there a thread safe option for the List, in my understanding ConcurrentBag will not be a right Data structure, since it cannot be used exactly like a list, it doesn't fill data in order and we cannot refer to elements using index like [0].
- For Making List access thread safe, will be it be fine to just lock the modification operation, but Read needn't be locked, so we can use a simple Lock
- Will ReaderWriterLock better option for such a List, where there can be multiple Readers and Writers accessing the List at same time.

Please note the Concurrent Dictionary is static, since it behind a Rest API and we need to persist the data for multiple users across various requests. Please let me know if question needs further clarification.

Comment: Do all the using threads require write access to the list, or is it just a small subset? The answer to this will influence your choice of implementations.

Comment: Also note that in general, having one thread removing items from a list that another thread is reading is fraught with peril. Even if all the CRUD operations are protected by a lock, simple code like `if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];` is buggy. If you can explain your intended usage of this list among the threads, we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: @Matthew Watson, usage needs to be genuinely parallel in nature, where Read / Write on same List would be carried out at same point of time. Scenario could be one thread modifying the list (add / delete / update), on other hand another thread would be using the list in a Linq query to fetch data / subset, thus would have got the enumerator to the List. After some research I have understood, that in this scenario Enumeratror would get invalidated due to List modification, so I need to a solution to overcome it. Would ReaderWriter lock be a good idea or we have something more elegant available.

Comment: Another thought, In case I plan to replace the List by ConcurrentBag<T>, which also provides an enumerator to be used in Linq queries, then what are the areas  where this data structure would differ from a List<T> in programmatic aspect. Is there a scope of getting in an issue ?
My understanding is, I can do all that is possible with List in this case too, instead of index access, I have to search for an element, but it will completely take away my thread safety concerns.

Comment: If you are passing a reference to the list around, all hope of making it threadsafe is lost. Your only sensible recourse is to have a method which returns a COPY of the list.

Comment: I do not foresee a situation, where list will be passed around in functions, since it is part of a static data structure, so would be accessible within the class to be used for read / write. 
For a moment if I assume that passing is required, exclusive lock for a user list would exist to ensure one thread read / write it at a given point of time. even if I copy / clone, still I need to work on thread safe access. In case I have to choose between ConcurrentQueue<T> and ConcurrentBag<T>, which data structure do you think will be a better fit.

Comment: I would think that ConcurrentQueue<T> would be better if you need to access the elements in the same order that they were added. ConcurrentBag<T> does not preserve ordering.